# IFrame appendChild missing child after page loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an IFrame into which I dynamically load content, once the content has been loaded I need to add a couple of divs after the content. There are two issues I can't work out.

One, AddIFrameIncludes is called twice (addEventListener is only called once).

Two, when I debug and stop after appendChild, I can see the new div has been added to the IFrame (twice) but when I allow the code to complete and inspect the iframe the new divs are no longer there.

```
<iframe id="helpBody" class="content" name="topic" frameborder="0" style="display: block;" src="LandingPage.html"></iframe>

LFANavi.AddIFrameIncludes = function () {
  makeRequest('GET', 'iFrameIncludes.html')
    .then(function (data) {
      let myIFrame = document.getElementById("helpBody");
      if (myIFrame) {
        let newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
        newDiv.innerHTML=data.responseText;
        myIFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
      }
    })
}

LFANavi.SetIFrame = function (fileName) {
  let myIFrame = document.getElementById("helpBody");
  if (myIFrame) {
    myIFrame.removeEventListener("load", LFANavi.AddIFrameIncludes()); //Should I do this?
    myIFrame.addEventListener("load", LFANavi.AddIFrameIncludes(), true);
    myIFrame.contentWindow.focus();
    myIFrame.setAttribute('src', fileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: A function call cannot replace a function reference when the called function doesn't return a function ... I.e. you're calling `AddIFrameIncludes` when you're supposed to just refer it, and never detach/attach any event listener to the iframe.

Comment: In other words, remove the (). Ugh, that was simple wasn't it.